# get mvn release:rollback to delete tag in GIT

Tags: git, maven, rollback, maven-release-plugin, git-tag

I have a maven project which is stored in our GIT repository. When I make a release of this project with `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` sometimes it fails in the later step but a tag is created for this release anyway. This tag doesn't get removed with `mvn release:rollback`, and if I try to prepare the release again it fails with this tag-already-exists error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project lwl-module: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: tag 'lwl-module-1.5.1' already exists
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Is there a way to get `mvn release:rollback` to delete the last tag in our GIT repository?

I'm using this release plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported by the Maven Release Plugin.

See here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/rollback-release.html

> The created branch/tag in SCM for the release is removed. Note: This is not yet implemented so you will need to manually remove the branch/tag from your SCM. For more info see [MRELEASE-229](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-229).

The ticket (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-229) has been open since 2007.

Comment: Update from December 2019: The bug is marked as fixed. According to the ticket, the version of the maven release plugin that fixes this bug is 3.0.0-M1.

Comment: I confirm it's fixed. I've just tested it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the problem that caused `mvn release:perfom` to fail, you can also just not rollback the release and after having fixed the problem run `mvn release:perform` directly, without running `mvn release:prepare`.

Comment: That's a good point - I have done that before in similar cases. It might not work all the time, but in some cases it was the right solution!

Answer (score 1):

The plugin version 3.0.0-M1 fixes this. The previous versions won't remove the tag.

I am posting this as an answer to make it more obvious. I got that from @jechterhoff comment. Please vote him up.